# How to make my search bar cover the title in the toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I have a toolbar in my Android application. I have the activity's title shown in the toolbar. I have a search icon and I want to expand it to cover the rest of the toolbar, including the title. However, it only covers part of the title. How to cover the whole part of it?

The code of the search bar:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the maximum width of the search bar to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. It will cover the whole part of the title.

```
mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```